# Setting a variable in symfony that will be readable in another module?

Tags: symfony1

I've taken on a symfony project that someone else built.  As such I don't know that much about how it works really.  I've been doing various changes over the last 6 months, so have a vague idea... but this problem has stumped me.

I'm optimistically hoping that you guys will be able to help, just by going off of the filenames/directory structure.  So I'll try to keep it simple.

Something I know inside...

```
/apps/frontend/modules/search/actions.class.php
```

Needs to be visible to...

```
/apps/frontend/modules/contact/templates/_minicontact.php
```

These two files are output into this template:

```
/apps/frontend/templates/pageDetails.php
```

with the following two lines of code:

```
<?php echo $sf_content ?>

and...

<?php include_component('contact','minicontact'); ?>
```

I've tried setting $this->myvar in the first file, and checking both $this->myVar and $myVar in the second file, and I've had no luck.

BODGING IS *FINE*.  I just want the quickest and simplest way to achieve this.  The client will be getting a completely new site in the next few months, so there's no need to do this "nicely".  Just give me the quick and dirty! :)

I'm sure the answer is very simple...  I've spent quite a while with get_defined_vars trying to figure out where I need to be putting it, but to no avail.

THANK YOU!

edit: Symfony v1.2, though I doubt the version makes any difference to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

I just noticed your path for pageDetails. It msut be an alternate layout. In that case you need pass the variable up to the layout. Typically this would be done with a slot from withing the view being rendered. But you havent provided enough info to know if this is going to work because you may need this value passed up from multiple views from within multiple modules.

Therefore the easiest solution is probably going to be to jsut duplicate whatever logic produces the value in the minicontact component.

```
// in /apps/frontend/modules/contact/actions/components.class.php
public function executeMinicontact() 
{
   // add the logic to produce the value for $myVar here and then:
   $this->myVar = 'theValue';
}
```

---

Im confused as to why `$sf_content` would be echoed in `pageDetails.php` which should be a view for a given module. Normally `$sf_content` would only be seen `layout.php`.

Any how you pass parameter to a component or a partial like so:

```
<?php include_component('contact','minicontact', array('myVar' => 'yourValue'); ?>
```

ofcourse that assumes that the value you want to pass to `minicontact` is already present in the `pageDetails.php`. If its not then you would need to add it to the view as a variable in your actions class - for example

```
// note this is the method name by convention but it may not be whats actually
// your pageDetails.php - you can get info about what action is being executed
// from the debug bar in the dev environment.
public function executePageDetails(sfRequest $request)
{
   $this->myVar = 'the value';
}
```

then in `pageDetails.php`:

```
<?php include_component('contact','minicontact', array('myVar' => $myVar); ?>
```

Comment: I think I confused you with a mistake - I meant pagedetails.php.  No capital "D", so it's not directly related to a module's action.It's in the same folder as layout.php - there's a few different ones.

Comment: Yeah i caught the path after the fact... see my update about adding to the `executeMinicontact` method.

Comment: I have successfully made a horrible mess of it, but I've got it working, which is all I care about at 3am.  I was very tempted to resort to using a session variable... not sure why I just didn't to be honest!